How can I parse a JSON file with references in a .NET Native AOT project?
Deserializing JSON files using System.Text.Json in a Native AOT project requires the source generation API, which takes a JsonSerializerContext object. I've managed that.
Now it appears that the JSON files I need to parse can include references. Here's a simplified example:
{
    "definitions": {
        "someProperty": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "properties": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions"
    }
}

According to Microsoft, to support this I need feed the deserializer with the option to preserve references, using a the ReferenceHandler property of JsonSerializerOptions object.
I didn't see any JsonSerializer.Deserialize() overload which takes both a JsonSerializerOptions and a JsonSerializerContext, and this led me to discover that with source generation, the options should be set as an attribute on the context instead of provided as a call argument – like so:
[ JsonSourceGenerationOptions( WriteIndented = true ) ]
[ JsonSerializable( typeof( SomeType ) ) ]
    
public partial class InterestingTypeSourceGenerationContext: JsonSerializerContext
{
}

The problem is that this attribute, JsonSourceGenerationOptionsAttribute, does not have the ReferenceHandler property mentioned in the article, that JsonSerializerOptions does.
How then, do I parse references when using the source generation API?

The System.Text.Json reference tracking mechanism will not help you here because the "$ref" value is in JSON Pointer syntax, and STJ does not support that syntax.  See Link one part of a JSON document to another, which shows how you could preprocess the JSON to resolve the link.  Does that answer your question?

I was considering preprocessing as a possible solution, so thanks for the clarification about STJ and for helping to cement that direction.

Glad to help.  As an aside, it the reference were in STJ format I believe it would be possible to use a ReferenceHandler along with a JsonSerializerContext.
